# Separate functions from the same class in multiple files

Tags: c++, qt

Is it a good practice to separate the functions of the same class in multiple `.cpp` files or all the functions should be in the same file?

For example:

**foobar.h**

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

#include <QDebug>

class FooBar
{
public:
    FooBar();

    void foo();
    void bar();
};

#endif // FOOBAR_H
```

**foobar.cpp**

```
#include "foobar.h"

FooBar::FooBar()
{
    qDebug() << "Constructor";
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foobar.h"

void FooBar::foo()
{
    qDebug() << "Foo";
}
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "foobar.h"

void FooBar::bar()
{
    qDebug() << "Bar";
}
```

**Note**: I only added the Qt tag because the example was generated in Qt, but this is a C++ related question.

Comment: This is a matter of team policy and subject to opinion. Having said that, I have always put the implementations of all the member functions of a class in one .cpp file.

Comment: The only time I've ever split a class's members into multiple .cpp files was for an archive file library I built where I wanted to separate zlib and bzip2 related functions so you didn't have to link against libraries you weren't using.

Comment: by default you better put all of them in one file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine doesn't care. So the sole driver for your decision will be the human at the center of it all: the developer.

Consider a book. Would you rather have the book as a complete entity, perhaps separated into chapters, or chunked into paragraphs on little pieces of paper? Locality of reference is important, and the implementation of a class should fit into a single file. Implementations of closely related classes could also all go into a single file if the code is easier to maintain that way. Heck, the entire project could go into a single file if it's small enough.

Personally, I find that things get hard to navigate after a single `.cpp` file is more than 3-4k lines long. But having lots of files with less than 500 lines each in them is just as painful. IDEs reduce some of the pain by providing easier navigation between the uses, declarations and definitions, of course, but files too small are almost never helpful in project comprehension. E.g. Java's insistence on one-public-class-per-file and on a 1:1 relationship between is a scourge in this respect and is at odds with what we know of cognitive psychology.

Comment: Thanks for exposing your opinion @Kuba Ober. My class has about 2k of lines, so I don't think it is a big deal to keep all functions in the same `.cpp` file. If someday I need to include more functions in this class maybe I can think about split it into multiple files.

Comment: @KelvinS Oh, you misunderstood me then. If a *single* class doesn't fit into a sanely sized `.cpp` file, it's too bit. You need to factor it out. In my experience, usually you'd lave core functionality, and factor out several small helper classes.

Comment: Ok, I understood now. I will think in a way to refactor it to keep the core functionality in the same class and split the small functionalities into multiple classes for specific purposes. This is probably a better idea than just split the functions in multiple `.cpp` files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of the code of the functions, I personally when the size of the code is little I prefer to have it all in a single `.h` file:

**foobar.h**

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

#include <QDebug>

class FooBar {
public:
    FooBar() {
        qDebug() << "Constructor";
    }

    void foo() {
        qDebug() << "Foo";
    }

    void bar() {
        qDebug() << "Bar";
    }
};

#endif // FOOBAR_H
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @Diego91b. I personally don't like this approach too much. In my opinion, the header files should be used only for functions and variables definitions, and the code itself should be placed in the `.cpp` files.